# Finding pins for relay

Tags: relay

I recently ordered a 50 pack of relays on sale for 5 dollars at electronic goldmine. They have 9 pins each and they are labled rk1-24v Ark112 910 25m. I know that they require 24 volts but I can't figure out where the coil is and where the connections like NO and NC are, nor can I find a datasheet that tells me this. I tried hooking up 24 volts to different pins, but I heard no click. So how can I find the right pins to hook the relays up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 50 of them, one easy way to figure the pins out would be to crack one open and have a look inside. The coil and connections should be clearly visible.

Another way is to use some Google-Fu and try the code or parts of it (you can add "relay" or "datasheet" to help narrow things down) and you may come up with something. I just had a go and I think this looks like your part's [datasheet](http://www.panasonic-electric-works.co.uk/catalogues/downloads/relays/ds_61311_en_rk.pdf).

[image: Relay]

It should look something like the above if it is the right datasheet.
If you look closely you can see a similar format for rest of your code on the package example (the ARK-110 612 25W bit)

Since yours appears to the "single side stable version", this should be the pinout for it:

[image: Relay Pinout]

Comment: Figured it out, I guess polarity matters on this relay!

Comment: @skyler - If that's true, they probably have a built-in flyback protection diode.

Comment: So what do they mean by high frequency? Is it

Comment: The time that it takes it to switch between it's two states?

Comment: @skyler - No, it means it's capable of passing high frequencies through it, i.e. it has a high bandwidth (up to 1.5GHz according to the datasheet) This is why it says it's a "Microwave Relay" and mentions typical applications of satellite tuners, test equipment, etc. It's not a "typical" general purpose relay (e.g. for power switching), it's for switching signals, hence the 50/75 Ohm impedance and low current specs.